# node-postgres $1 IS NULL error

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am using node-postgres to write a web app backend, and I am running into this error:

```
error: could not determine data type of parameter $1
    at Connection.parseE (/home/***/niche-api/node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:539:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/***/niche-api/node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:366:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/***/niche-api/node/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:172:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:542:20)
```

The goal of my query is to accept a query parameter passed in from the node express app, but to not filter the database query if the parameter does not exist in the api call.  For example, if my parameter is called `variableType` and it is set to `tmax` (e.g., `variableType=tmax`), the database only responds with records with variableType of tmax.  If the endpoint is hit without the query parameter, the database returns all records.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM variableTypes WHERE 1 = 1 AND ($1 IS NULL or $1 = variableTypeAbbreviation);
```

And I am calling it like this:

```
app.get("/variables", function(req, res){
  //get a list of the variables in the database
  var variableType = req.query.variableType
  if (variableType == undefined){
    variableType = null;
  }
  var client = new pg.Client({
    user: keys.user,
    password: keys.password,
    database: keys.dbName,
    hostname: keys.hostname
  })
  client.connect(function(err){
    if (err){
      res.json(err);
    }

    var query = client.query({name: 'variableSelect', text: "SELECT * FROM variableTypes WHERE 1 = 1 AND ($1 IS NULL or $1 = variableTypeAbbreviation);", values:[variableType]});
    console.log(query)
    query.on('row', function(row, result){
      console.log("Got row")
      result.addRow(row)
    })
    query.on('end', function(result){
      console.log("Done.")
      res.json(result)
      client.end()
    })
```

I've narrowed it down to the problem being located in the section of the query `($1 IS NULL)`. I don't really know where to go from here.  I've written a similar query in python (using psycopg2), which works, which makes me think that it is more related to the node package.

```
  query =   select variableTypeID, variableType, variableTypeAbbreviation
    from variableTypes
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND
        (%(abbreviation)s is NULL or %(abbreviation)s LIKE lower(variableTypes.variableTypeAbbreviation) )
        AND  (%(fullName)s is NULL or %(fullName)s = variableTypes.variableType )

cursor.execute(query, {'fullName': fullName, 'abbreviation' : abbreviation})
```

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `$1 IS NULL`, where `$1` is treated as a dynamic column name, which is not allowed in prepared statements, due to the protections against SQL injection implemented by the database server.

**UPDATE**

If you want to format your queries freely, while also without the risk of an SQL injection, check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise). And to properly format names for schema, table or column see [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names).

Comment: Thanks! That was my conclusion as well.  Is there any way to achieve the same result in sql without this syntax?

Comment: @SCOTTFARLEY, yes, without using prepared statements, with simple query parameterization. I have edited my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

think you need set the type of the `$1` parameter, was my case

`CASE WHEN $1::varchar IS NOT NULL THEN category = $1::varchar ELSE true END and`